# Issue with TabControl which ContentTemplate contains a TabControl

Tags: wpf, templates, tabcontrol, selecteditem

In my WPF application, I have a `TabControl` named *ParentTabControl*, which ContentTemplate is composed of several controls, including a `TabControl` named *ChildTabControl*.

*ParentTabControl contains*, say, 2 tabs (each one bound to a different source), where as *ChildTabControl* always contain 1 tab. I'm focusing the first tab of *ParentTabControl*. By default, the first (the only one) tab of *ChildTabControl* is selected. The problem is that, if I switch to the second tab of *ParentTabControl*, the tab of its *ChildTabControl* is not selected. Is that a normal behavior? How can I do to always select a tab?

I hope I'm clear enough. Here is some code:

### ParentTabControl:

```
<TabControl Name="ParentTabControl"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ParentItemsSource}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ContentTemplate}"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

### ContentTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">
    <TabControl Name="ChildTabControl"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ItemToObservableCollectionConverter }}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

### ItemsSource:

```
public ObservableCollection<ParentData> ParentItemsSource { get; set; }

public class ParentData
{
    public ChildData ChildItemsSource { get; set; }
}
```

### Converter:

```
public class ItemToObservableCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<object> { value };
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: We are going to need to see your `ControlTemplate` in order to debug this.

Comment: I added the code of the ContentTemplate, if it is what you mean by ControlTemplate.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had a reading comprehension error there. Bad to StackOverflow pre-morning coffee :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have one and only one item, why do you want a `TabControl`? If you just want to have an element with a header, you can do that in your `ContentTemplate`.

In order to fix the issue you're seeing, however, have you tried setting `SelectedIndex="0"` on the `ChildTabControl`? That should force it to always be selected.

**EDIT for other possible solution**

Well, I was able to replicate this, but it only happens intermittently in my test.

I think the easiest way you can fix this is to set the `SelectedItem` of the child `TabControl` to the `ChildItemsSource`:

```
<TabControl Name="ChildTabControl"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ItemToObservableCollectionConverter }}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ChildItemsSource}" />
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue, but this definitely fixes it.

Comment: Yes, I could just remove the TabControl in this case, but I would have the same issue whatever the number of tabs in the *ChildTabControl*. 

I already tried to set SelectedIndex to 0, but the behavior remains the same. Actually, it's like the tabs of *ChildTabControl* belong to the same TabControl (because of the Template?).

Comment: Okay, I've added a solution to the problem. I'm not sure what is causing it, but I was able to fix it in my test app.

Comment: It also happens intermittently in my application. Anyway, your solution solved my problem, thanks :)